# Can't read config server uri from bootstrap.yml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I'm trying to create a eureka server registry with the following **pom** to connect to config server but it fails to connect config server, because it fails to read correct config server uri from **bootstrap.yml file**;

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>yyy</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <artifactId>cloudregistryapp</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

I had to exclude **servlet-api** but that's another subject. In my parent pom (which is the other maven module);

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>Greenwich.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

And here's the **bootstrap.yml** in the **app/resources** directory;

```
spring:
  application:
    name: cloudregistry
  cloud:
    config:
      fail-fast: true
      uri: http://localhost:8080

eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    server:
      waitTimeInMsWhenSyancEmpty: 0
```

I'm expecting to see trying to connect to **localhost:8080** for config server. But it spits out the following output;

```
2019-06-18 14:52:02.701 DEBUG 32228 --- [           main] .c.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application started with classpath: unknown
2019-06-18 14:52:02.929 DEBUG 32228 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Loading source class org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapImportSelectorConfiguration
2019-06-18 14:52:03.312  INFO 32228 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$91d1cbee] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-06-18 14:52:03.411 DEBUG 32228 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 


============================
CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT
============================


Positive matches:
-----------------

   ConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration#configServicePropertySource matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.cloud.config.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor' (OnBeanCondition)

   ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration#configurationPropertiesBeans matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration#configurationPropertiesRebinder matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.TextEncryptor' (OnClassCondition)

   PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration#propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)


Negative matches:
-----------------

   ConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration.RetryConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.retry.annotation.Retryable' (OnClassCondition)

   DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled) did not find property 'spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled' (OnPropertyCondition)

   EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration.RsaEncryptionConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - Keystore nor key found in Environment (EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration.KeyCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.security.rsa.crypto.RsaSecretEncryptor' (OnClassCondition)

   EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration.VanillaEncryptionConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnMissingClass found unwanted class 'org.springframework.security.rsa.crypto.RsaSecretEncryptor' (OnClassCondition)

   EurekaDiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled) did not find property 'spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled' (OnPropertyCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator' (OnClassCondition)


Exclusions:
-----------

    None


Unconditional classes:
----------------------

    None



2019-06-18 14:52:03.534 DEBUG 32228 --- [           main] .c.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application started with classpath: unknown

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.5.RELEASE)

2019-06-18 14:52:03.566  INFO 32228 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
2019-06-18 14:52:03.588 DEBUG 32228 --- [           main] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : HTTP GET http://localhost:8888/application/default
2019-06-18 14:52:03.651 DEBUG 32228 --- [           main] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Accept=[application/xml, text/xml, application/json, application/*+xml, application/*+json]
2019-06-18 14:52:03.655  INFO 32228 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Connect Timeout Exception on Url - http://localhost:8888. Will be trying the next url if available
```

And naturally it throws a connection exception since it doesn't recognize the URL in the **bootstrap.yml** file.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You talk about Eureka and ask for config server. What are you trying to do? Eureka is service discovery not config server.

Comment: No setting up eureka by connecting to config server, fixed the first sentence.

Comment: But you have both eureka client and config client in your client project?

Comment: The poms and yml files here are a part of the eureka server which tries to connect to a cloud config server, but it doesn't recognize the bootstrap.yml file somehow and tries to connect to wrong config uri.

Comment: and you are sure that you have the bootstrap.yml in the classpath when starting the app?

Comment: If your eureka server is the client so you should set the correct dependency: `<artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>`

Comment: Can you post the complete debug logs? I do not see anything wrong with the configuration.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I'm using intellij's start functionality, it works perfectly if I put `application.properties`

@akuma8 I thought `spring-cloud-starter-config` already includes it?? But tried to add it anyways, didn't work.

@Ajinkya I'm starting with --debug and sharing the logs in the question now.

Comment: For starters you should not be mixing versions. Remove the `version` tag from the `org.springframework.cloud` dependencies, those are managed through the `spring-cloud-dependencies` imported bom. Also make sure that your `bootstrap.yml` is in the correct location. Or try an `bootstrap.properties` instead.

Comment: It's fairly basic functionality. Nothing you've shared gives me any indication why it wouldn't work. Can you share a project that recreates the problem?

Comment: @M.Deinum `properties` didn't work either. I'll try to remove `version` tag 

@spencergibb in fact, there're only the given files and properties in the project. There's nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason of failure was that I was using my own parent pom, after changing it with `spring-boot-starter-parent` it started to work.

Of course I copied required parts such as `distributionManagement` into the eureka service's pom.

The main reason was that spring boot parent pom uses `resources` directive in pom as below;

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

Adding this manually to project did the trick !